# school project; UDP connection to open/ close a hatch door

Tags: java, android, android-layout

this is my first post here so please forgive me  if I have put this in the wrong section.
For our school project, i want to open/ close a door by an Android Tablet. For the connection with the ecu of our door i have a can-wlan modul from avisaro.

The problem is that i am not an expert in programming android applications, i dont know anything about it.

from a former projekt i got this UDP THread (UDP_Verbindung ja va)
can someone help me combine the UDP Thread with the layout, which you can see down here?

CAN data byte output should look like this:

button "Öffnen" (open), 13. byte: {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

button "Schließen"(close), 14.byte:{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

button "STOP", 15. byte:{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}

Progressbar ("Heckklappengeschwindigkeit"), 16. byte, value: 50...100

UDP_Verbindung.java:

```
    public class UDP_Verbindung implements Runnable{

        private static final String TAGUDP = "UDP";
        final int UDP_Target_Port = 12345;
        private Thread threadUDP = null;
        private boolean isrunning = false;
        private DatagramSocket udpSocket = null;
        byte[] buffin = new byte[28];
        byte[] buffout = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
        DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(buffin,buffin.length);
        DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(buffout,buffout.length);
        int CAN_ID;
        int CAN_Length;
        private int udpStatus = 0;
        private Handler uiHandler = null;
        private int sendFlag = 0;
    String ip = "168.192.0.74";
    InetAddress addr = intToInetAddress(ipStringToInt( "192.168.0.74"));
    public int receive = 1; 
    private Set<String> listenToIds;


    public UDP_Verbindung(Handler uiHandler) {
        this.uiHandler = uiHandler;
        listenToIds = Collections.<String>emptySet();
    }

    public void setMessages(Set<String> messages){
        listenToIds = messages;
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "New Message IDs to listen to: ");
        for(String strId: listenToIds) {
            Log.d(TAGUDP, strId);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

         try
            {
             Log.d(TAGUDP,"Verbindungsaufbau");   
             udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(UDP_Target_Port);
             udpSocket.setSoTimeout( 3000 );           
            } catch (SocketException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAGUDP,"Verbindungsaufbau fehlgeschlagen");
                this.stop_service();

            }

            udpStatus = 1;
            Message msg1 = new Message();
            Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
            msg1.what = 1;
            b1.putInt("udpStatus", udpStatus);
            msg1.setData(b1);
            uiHandler.sendMessage(msg1);

            while (isrunning)
            {

                try
                {
                udpSocket.receive(in);
                //Log.d(TAGUDP,"Data received:");

                } 

                catch (IOException ex)
                {

                        Log.d(TAGUDP,"hier??");
                }



    InetAddress senderIP = in.getAddress();
                    int senderPort = in.getPort();
                    //Log.d(TAGUDP, senderIP.toString() + ":" + Integer.toString(senderPort) );
                    buffin = in.getData();//---------------------Einlesen des Inhalts einer CAN Nachricht
                    /*Log.d(TAGUDP, "LOsgeths:");
                    for (int o = 0; o < 28; o++){
                        Log.d(TAGUDP, buffin[o] + " ");
                    }*/
                    //Log.d(TAGUDP, senderIP.toString() + ":" + Integer.toString(senderPort) );
                    CAN_ID = buffin[8] + buffin[9]*256;//----------Ermitteln der CAN ID einer CAN Nachricht
                    String CAN_ID_hex = Integer.toHexString(CAN_ID);
                    if(listenToIds.contains(CAN_ID_hex)){
                        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Neue CAN Nachricht mit der ID " + CAN_ID_hex);
                        CAN_Length = buffin[6] & 15;//---------------Ermitteln der Länge einer CAN Nachricht
                        //Log.d(TAGUDP,"ID: " + CAN_ID + "    ");
                        byte[] canData = ne

w byte[CAN_Length];
                    for (int l = 0; l < CAN_Length; l++){
                        canData[l] = buffin[12+l];
                        //Log.d(TAGUDP, buffin[12+l] + " ");
                        //Log.d(TAGUDP, Integer.toString(byteToUnsignedInt(buffin[12+l])));
                    }
                    Message msg = new Message();
                    Bundle b = new Bundle();
                    msg.what = 2;
                    b.putString("CAN_ID", CAN_ID_hex);
                    b.putByteArray("CAN_DATA",  canData);
                    b.putInt("CAN_LENGTH", CAN_Length);
                    msg.setData(b);
                    uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                }
            }


        }  


public static int byteToUnsignedInt(byte b) {
        return (0x00 << 24 | b & 0xff);
      }

public void start_Service(){
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Start Thread");  
        this.threadUDP = new Thread(this);
        isrunning = true;
        threadUDP.start();
    }

public void stop_service() {

        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Trenne Verbindung"); 
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Warte bis Thread durchgelaufen");
        isrunning = false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                if (threadUDP != null) {
                    threadUDP.join(500);
                }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Thread durchgelaufen");
        if (udpSocket != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAGUDP, "Schließe Socket");
            udpSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAGUDP, "geschlossen");
        }
        threadUDP = null;
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "UDP Thread geschlossen");

        udpStatus = 0;
        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        msg.what = 1;
        b.putInt("udpStatus", udpStatus);
        msg.setData(b);
        uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    public void setsendFlagValue(int flag) {
        this.sendFlag = flag;
    }

    public int getsendFlagValue() {
        return this.sendFlag;
    }

    public static int ipStringToInt(String str) {
         int result = 0;
         String[] array = str.split("\\.");
         if (array.length != 4) return 0;
         try {
             result = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
             result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
             result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
             result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
         } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
             return 0;
         }
         return result;
     }

    public static InetAddress intToInetAddress(int hostAddress) {
        InetAddress inetAddress;
        byte[] addressBytes = { (byte)(0xff & hostAddress),
                                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
                                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
                                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 24)) };

        try {
           inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(addressBytes);
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
           return null;
        }
        return inetAddress;
    }

}
```

my layout:
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwWAN.jpg)

in code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="de.yargeldi.heckklappenapp.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Öffnen"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginTop="19dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Schließen"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="STOP"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/hochschule" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Heckklappengeschwindigkeit:"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:max="50"
        android:progressTint="#FF0000"
        android:thumbTint="#0000CD"
        android:indeterminateTint="#0000CD"
        android:foregroundTint="#0000CD"
        android:backgroundTint="#0000CD" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="50%-100%:"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Heckklappenöffnungswinkel:"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView3" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I tried to complete it, i know that there are all of mistakes, because i am an absolut beginner and i do not know how to use the commands.
I would be very happy, if someone could show how i have to do it right.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Set;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button openbutton,closebutton,stopbutton;
    Handler handler;
    Thread thread;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////////////////////Button Finder//////////////////////
        openbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonopen);
        closebutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonclose);
        stopbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonstop);

        /////////////////////Button Listener///////////////////////
        openbutton.setOnClickListener(openbuttonListener);
        closebutton.setOnClickListener(closebuttonListener);
        stopbutton.setOnClickListener(stopbuttonListener);


        thread= new Thread(new UDP_Verbindung(handler));
        thread.start();
    }
}

public Button.OnClickListener openbuttonListener= new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        buffout[12]=1;
        new sendThread().execute();
    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener closebuttonListener= new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        buffout[13]=1;
        new sendThread().execute();
    }

};

public Button.OnClickListener stopbuttonListener= new Button.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        buffout[14]=1;
        new sendThread().execute();
    }

};

public class sendThread extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Boolean>{

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... arg0) {

        try {
            inet_addr = addr;
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(buffout, buffout.length, inet_addr, UDP_Target_Port);
        try {
            socket= new DatagramSocket();
            socket.send(out);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}

class UDP_Verbindung implements Runnable{

    private static final String TAGUDP = "UDP";
    final int UDP_Target_Port = 12345;
    private Thread threadUDP = null;
    private boolean isrunning = false;
    private DatagramSocket udpSocket = null;
    byte[] buffin = new byte[28];
    byte[] buffout = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    DatagramPacket in = new DatagramPacket(buffin,buffin.length);
    DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(buffout,buffout.length);
    int CAN_ID;
    int CAN_Length;
    private int udpStatus = 0;
    private Handler uiHandler = null;
    private int sendFlag = 0;
    String ip = "168.192.0.74";
    InetAddress addr = intToInetAddress(ipStringToInt( "192.168.0.74"));
    public int receive = 1;
    private Set<String> listenToIds;


    public UDP_Verbindung(Handler uiHandler) {
        this.uiHandler = uiHandler;
        listenToIds = Collections.<String>emptySet();
    }

    public void setMessages(Set<String> messages){
        listenToIds = messages;
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "New Message IDs to listen to: ");
        for(String strId: listenToIds) {
            Log.d(TAGUDP, strId);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        try
        {
            Log.d(TAGUDP,"Verbindungsaufbau");
            udpSocket = new DatagramSocket(UDP_Target_Port);
            udpSocket.setSoTimeout( 3000 );
        } catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            Log.d(TAGUDP,"Verbindungsaufbau fehlgeschlagen");
            this.stop_service();

        }

        udpStatus = 1;
        Message msg1 = new Message();
        Bundle b1 = new Bundle();
        msg1.what = 1;
        b1.putInt("udpStatus", udpStatus);
        msg1.setData(b1);
        uiHandler.sendMessage(msg1);

        while (isrunning)
        {

            try
            {
                udpSocket.receive(in);
                //Log.d(TAGUDP,"Data received:");

            }

            catch (IOException ex)
            {

                Log.d(TAGUDP,"hier??");
            }



            InetAddress senderIP = in.getAddress();
            int senderPort = in.getPort();
            //Log.d(TAGUDP, senderIP.toString() + ":" + Integer.toString(senderPort) );
            buffin = in.getData();//---------------------Einlesen des Inhalts einer CAN Nachricht
                /*Log.d(TAGUDP, "LOsgeths:");
                for (int o = 0; o < 28; o++){
                    Log.d(TAGUDP, buffin[o] + " ");
                }*/
            //Log.d(TAGUDP, senderIP.toString() + ":" + Integer.toString(senderPort) );
            CAN_ID = buffin[8] + buffin[9]*256;//----------Ermitteln der CAN ID einer CAN Nachricht
            String CAN_ID_hex = Integer.toHexString(CAN_ID);
            if(listenToIds.contains(CAN_ID_hex)){
                Log.d(TAGUDP, "Neue CAN Nachricht mit der ID " + CAN_ID_hex);
                CAN_Length = buffin[6] & 15;//---------------Ermitteln der Länge einer CAN Nachricht
                //Log.d(TAGUDP,"ID: " + CAN_ID + "    ");
                byte[] canData = new byte[CAN_Length];
                for (int l = 0; l < CAN_Length; l++){
                    canData[l] = buffin[12+l];
                    //Log.d(TAGUDP, buffin[12+l] + " ");
                    //Log.d(TAGUDP, Integer.toString(byteToUnsignedInt(buffin[12+l])));
                }
                Message msg = new Message();
                Bundle b = new Bundle();
                msg.what = 2;
                b.putString("CAN_ID", CAN_ID_hex);
                b.putByteArray("CAN_DATA",  canData);
                b.putInt("CAN_LENGTH", CAN_Length);
                msg.setData(b);
                uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);
            }
        }


    }


    public static int byteToUnsignedInt(byte b) {
        return (0x00 << 24 | b & 0xff);
    }

    public void start_Service(){
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Start Thread");
        this.threadUDP = new Thread(this);
        isrunning = true;
        threadUDP.start();
    }

    public void stop_service() {

        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Trenne Verbindung");
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Warte bis Thread durchgelaufen");
        isrunning = false;
        while(true) {
            try {
                if (threadUDP != null) {
                    threadUDP.join(500);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "Thread durchgelaufen");
        if (udpSocket != null)
        {
            Log.d(TAGUDP, "Schließe Socket");
            udpSocket.close();
            Log.d(TAGUDP, "geschlossen");
        }
        threadUDP = null;
        Log.d(TAGUDP, "UDP Thread geschlossen");

        udpStatus = 0;
        Message msg = new Message();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        msg.what = 1;
        b.putInt("udpStatus", udpStatus);
        msg.setData(b);
        uiHandler.sendMessage(msg);

    }

    public void setsendFlagValue(int flag) {
        this.sendFlag = flag;
    }

    public int getsendFlagValue() {
        return this.sendFlag;
    }

    public static int ipStringToInt(String str) {
        int result = 0;
        String[] array = str.split("\\.");
        if (array.length != 4) return 0;
        try {
            result = Integer.parseInt(array[3]);
            result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[2]);
            result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[1]);
            result = (result << 8) + Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static InetAddress intToInetAddress(int hostAddress) {
        InetAddress inetAddress;
        byte[] addressBytes = { (byte)(0xff & hostAddress),
                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
                (byte)(0xff & (hostAddress >> 24)) };

        try {
            inetAddress = InetAddress.getByAddress(addressBytes);
        } catch(UnknownHostException e) {
            return null;
        }
        return inetAddress;
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to implement the given UDP thread in my main Thread, in other words i want to create a main part, which allows me to send an array with 28 bytes, according to my buttons....How can i implement the UDP_Verbindung.java in my main part? How can i start the thread? How can i get the message "from" the handler? It would be a great help for me, if someone could show me in a few lines how to do.